# emulator: ERROR: Can't get kernel version from the kernel image file: '/media/anand/BUILD/aosp/out/target/product/generic/kernel-ranchu-64'

Tags: android, android-source

i am new AOSP build system  .  I followed all the steps given in following link
https://source.android.com/setup/build/building

to build Android from source .
took very recent tag **android-11.0.0_r7**

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-11.0.0_r7
repo sync -c -j8
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch aosp_arm-eng 
make -j8
```

Build is successful

```
removing out/target/product/generic/system-qemu.img.qcow2
out/host/linux-x86/bin/sgdisk --clear out/target/product/generic/system-qemu.img

#### build completed successfully (05:12:46 (hh:mm:ss)) ####
```

But when i run  emulator,  i get this message

```
emulator: ERROR: Can't get kernel version from the kernel image file: '/media/anand/BUILD/aosp/out/target/product/generic/kernel-ranchu-64'
```

Can anyone please help out , what i am doing wrong