# AOSP: Can't Run Emulator

Tags: android, android-source

I'm an AOSP newbie. I am following this [tutorial](https://liongueststudios.com/download-and-build-aosp-android11-custom-rom/).

I have successfully synced my repo to tag android-11.0.0_r29.

I set lunch to aosp_arm-eng (I've also tried aosp_x86_64-eng). The build reports:

```
...
[ 99% 90444/90520] //art/build/apex:art-check-debug-apex-gen generate art-check-debug-apex-gen.dummy
--bitness=auto, trying to autodetect. This may be incorrect!
  Detected multilib
[100% 90520/90520] Target vbmeta image: out/target/product/generic_arm64/vbmeta.img
    
#### build completed successfully (05:25:57 (hh:mm:ss)) ####
```

However, when I attempt to run the emulator:

```
clayton@ubuntu-20-aosp:~/aosp$ emulator
emulator: ERROR: Can't get kernel version from the kernel image file: '/home/clayton/aosp/prebuilts/qemu-kernel/arm64/ranchu/kernel-qemu'
```

Have not found a solution. Please help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64525315

Comment: I saw that post. It does not have a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I use `lunch sdk_phone_x86_64-userdebug`, and it works fine with `Android 11` on my x86 architecture laptop.

Comment: Yes, I eventually found that to be true also. Just odd that the doc (https://source.android.com/setup/build/building#emulate-an-android-device) states that aosp_arm-eng should work with the emulator. Another post on SO stated aosp_x86_64-eng worked with the emulator. I just don't understand why other targets don't work. I've seen references stating that arm targets run very slowly on x86 (but still should run).

Comment: Maybe they don't update doc on time. If you machine is `x86_64`, you should use target that compatible with `x86_ 64`. I don't know whether the `arm64` target can run correctly on `x86_64` machine, but I think it is used for `arm64` machine, such as `ChromBook` with `arm` processors.